# How to get started with an OAuth App for Zoom API connected to Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, zoom-sdk

I'm a teacher and have been teaching myself enough code in order to use Apps Script. I have read about and somewhat understand the idea of OAuth and see in principle how it should be able to be used to connect the Zoom API and Sheets API in order to make an attendance taking app. However, I don't get how to do some of the basics. For example, what to put in the OAuth redirect URL when making my App. Or even how to call the Zoom API from Sheets. Can I even use Javascript in order to call it? I haven't found much online that doesn't assume the basic knowledge. Also, most of the stuff online uses JWT, but I want to be able to share it far and wide so I think I need OAuth. Anyone know of a guide or something I can use to get started?

Based on answer's suggestion, I got the following code to work on Postman. Not sure how to change it for Apps Script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKVMTIzNn0.9Ol6oPrmbzvby5ch5-okkl7FMRG465Nu_zM0MVd91Ig");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "_zm_date_format=dd/mm/yy; cred=2AFAF4FB9881D6BE9A38BD86B63DF1CC");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.zoom.us/v2/report/meetings/92672781820/participants?page_size=30", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  
  
  
  
}
```

Note: Bearer changed and switched it to UrlFetchApp

Comment: See https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2 as mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Zoom API, but in taking a quick read of the documentation it appears they support both public and private apps. If you are new to this, my recommendation would be to first create a private app using JWT and get it working for yourself; after that, you can create a public app and employ OAuth so that others can install it. If you want to stick with Apps Script, you can look into the [Google Apps Script OAuth library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2).

After you create your app within Zoom and select JWT, it will provide you with an `api key` as well as `app secret` for your app - these are the credentials you will use in your API requests. Check out their documentation for how to make simple requests to the API using your credentials.

If you are new to APIs in general, a good place to start is to download Postman. This will enable you to test your API requests using your credentials and confirm everything is working. After you have a working request created in Postman, you can click on 'code' on the right and it will generate the Javascript code you can use to make calls to the Zoom API within Apps Script. Use `Javascript - Fetch` as it's the most similar to Apps Script's own [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) class. You will have to make some minor modifications to the pasted code from Postman to get it working in Apps Script.

For writing attendance to the Google Sheet, there should be some examples online of how to parse a JSON response from an API, push it to an array, and then `setValue()` within the Sheet. Hopefully the above is enough to get you started.

Comment: Wow, excellent respsonse! I put in the working code from Postman in my post (with bearer changed). Not sure what to change to get it to work in Apps Script.

Comment: Review the UrlFetchApp documentation - for example, UrlFetch calls it ``contentType`` instead of ``content-type`` like Javascript fetch